# non-static method filterdList(ArrayList<SuitcaseModel>) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: android, android-studio, methods, non-static

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxWST.png)

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java file**

```
public void filterdList(ArrayList<SuitcaseModel> filterStudent) {

    arrStudent=filterStudent;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4k8N.png)

**MainActivity.java**

```
RecyclerViewAdapter.filterdList(filterStudent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `RecyclerViewAdapter` you have to use object of `RecyclerViewAdapter`.

```
RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter();
recyclerViewAdapter.filterdList(filterStudent);
```

Comment: You already set the adapter to the RecyclerView. So use that object to filter the list.