# Unable to solve constructor applied to given types

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, searchview

I am doing a Semester project of our own app development. I am making a Recipe/Restaurant app.
The issue is that in my Restaurant.java is unable to get the RestaurantAdapter ->  public void setFilteredList as it has come with an error I am unable to solve after referring to [previous error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58678761/non-static-method-filterdlistarraylistsuitcasemodel-cannot-be-referenced-fro).

The current error I got was:

constructor RestaurantAdapter in class RestaurantAdapter cannot be applied to given types

> Error message

[image]

These are the Java and XML files that are used:

The java class:

> 1st half

[image]

> 2nd half

[image]

error part:

```
else{
RestaurantAdapter restaurantAdapter = new RestaurantAdapter();
restaurantAdapter.setFilteredList(filteredList);
}
```

RestaurantAdapter:

> Adpapter part 1

[image]

> Adpapter part 2

[image]

Apologies if the response is scuffed, this is my first time posting.
Greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

**Check this**

```
else{
    RestaurantAdapter restaurantAdapter = new RestaurantAdapter(getApplicationContext(),filteredList);
    restaurantAdapter.setFilteredList(filteredList);
 }
```

Comment: Hi, it is still unable to display the search result. do you mind referring to this new post I have posted?  Link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73146207/19629949